# GraphStream - No valid display found

Tags: java, graphstream

I'm following this [official tutorial](https://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Getting-Started/1.0/) of graphStream.
And I'm trying to run this example code taken from there:

```java
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.*;
    
public class Tutorial1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial 1");
    
        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("B");
        graph.addNode("C");
        graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
        graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
        graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");
    
        graph.display();
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot launch viewer.
    at org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:212)
    at org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:204)
    at org.test.Test.main(Test.java:23)
Caused by: org.graphstream.util.MissingDisplayException: No valid display found. Please check your System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui") statement.
    at org.graphstream.util.Display.getDefault(Display.java:79)
    at org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:209)
    ... 2 more
```

I did exactly what the tutorial showed.
what am I missing?
what does **"No valid display found."** means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this in a `Java` application, you need to use version 1.3.

Add the following dependencies. `Version 1.3`

- `gs-core`
- `gs-algo`
- `gs-ui`

**Main**

```
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.*;
    
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial 1");
        graph.setStrict(false);
        graph.setAutoCreate( true );
        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("B");
        graph.addNode("C");
        graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
        graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
        graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");
    
        graph.display();
    }
}
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sed.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaTestArea</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-algo</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Output**
[image]

**If you use version 2.0, it needs to be done in a `JavaFX`, `Swing`, or `Android` application.**

Comment: and I've tried to use version 1.3 and still no luck. the only difference is the error message,  now it's - **No UI package detected!**  instead of the message from the post - **No valid display found.**

Comment: I'm new to java's gui. do you know any code example for using Graphstream with swing or JavaFX I can use as a reference?

Comment: I got the same error you originally got until I used version 1.3. What version of Java are you using? What operating System?

Comment: I have never tried this with `JavaFX`. I will give it a try today.

Comment: "From the 2.0 version of GraphStream, the default viewer is no part of the gs-core package anymore. Viewers are available separately. Viewers are located in gs-ui-TECH modules, where TECH is the name of the GUI tech used"

Comment: I was able to get 2.0 to work by adding `gs-ui-swing` 2.0 as a dependency.